# a problem with computing binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics

I have a problem with computing the binomial coefficient in polynomial algebra. 
Let we have  $a=(a_1,...,a_n)$ and $b=(b_1,...,b_n)$ as an n-tuples such that $ (0,...0) \leq a ,b \leq (2^{m_1}-1,...,2^{m_n}-1)$ and $m\in \mathbb{N}^n$. Is it true if  we claim  $ a\choose b$ is equal to $(-1)^{\mid b \mid}$ such that  $\mid b\mid = b_1+...+b_n$ ?if so, why? I have already studied that  $ {a\choose b} =(-1)^{\mid b \mid}$ but I did not understand the reason for that?